# Speeding up a for loop in R

Tags: r, for-loop

I'm looking to run this for loop, but it takes an unacceptably long time (~20s) to execute.  x and y are predefined vectors of length 2000000.

```
for(i in 1:2000000)
{
    a <- runif(1)
    b <- runif(1)
    sqrtf <- sqrt(-log(b,10))

    x[i] <- sqrtf*cos(a)
    y[i] <- sqrtf*cos(b)
}
```

Any tricks available to speed this up a bit?

EDIT: fixed the sqrtf

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
n <- 2e6
set.seed(101)
a <- runif(n)
b <- runif(n)
sqrtf <- sqrt(-log10(b))
x <- sqrtf*cos(a)
y <- sqrtf*cos(b)
```

Comment: Why do you have the assignments to `x` and `y` ? You never use them.

Answer (score 3):

```
# just so you don't have to write 2000000 over and over
n <- 2e6
# so the results are replicable
set.seed(0)
# the meat and potatoes... this is "vectorized" code that you'll hear lots about
# as you study R
a <- runif(n)
b <- runif(n)
sqrtf <- sqrt( -log10(b) )
x <- sqrtf * cos(a)
y <- sqrtf * cos(b)
```

Answer (score 1):

`x <- sqrtexp*cos(runif(2e6))`